# A question regarding $\varphi: \text{Sym}(n) \to \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, permutations, group-homomorphism

I was reading a proof of the fact that $\varphi: \text{Sym}(n) \to \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\varphi(\sigma) = A_{\sigma}$ is a group homomorphism. Here $A_{\sigma} = [e_{\sigma(1)} \: e_{\sigma(2)} \: \cdots e_{\sigma(n)}]$ where the $e_i$'s are the standard basis vectors for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now the proof showed that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism in the following way:

Let $\sigma, \tau \in \text{Sym}(n)$ then $A_{\sigma} \cdot A_{\tau} = [e_{\sigma(1)} \: e_{\sigma(2)} \: \cdots e_{\sigma(n)}] \cdot [e_{\tau(1)} \: e_{\tau(2)} \: \cdots e_{\tau(n)}] = [e_{\sigma \circ \tau(1)} \: e_{\sigma \circ \tau(2)} \: \cdots e_{\sigma \circ \tau(n)}] = A_{\sigma \tau}$

My question regards the second equality. Though I can see that we need this equality to hold, it is not clear to me that the matrix multiplication will result in the permutation composition. If someone can provide some algebraic reasoning behind this, that would be helpful.

Comment: it's a lot clearer if you think of the matrices as linear maps

Comment: To elaborate on @Thorgott's comment: $A_\sigma$ is characterized by $A_\sigma e_i = e_{\sigma(i)}$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, $A_\sigma$ permutes the basis $\{e_i\}$ by $\sigma$, that is $A_\sigma e_i = e_{\sigma(i)}$. So $A_\sigma A_\tau$ and $A_{\sigma \tau}$ agree on each $e_i$, hence must be equal.

You can also get this symbolically from the matrix multiplication formulas. Let $\delta_{ij}$ denote the Kronecker delta, ie $\delta_{ij} = 1$ if $i = j$ and $0$ otherwise. This satisfies the property that $\sum_j x_j\delta_{jk} = x_k$. Thus
$$(A_\sigma A_\tau)_{ik} = \sum_j (A_\sigma)_{ij} (A_\tau)_{jk} = \sum_j\delta_{i\sigma(j)} \delta_{j\tau(k)} = \sum_j \delta_{i\sigma(\tau(k))} = (A_{\sigma \tau})_{ik}$$
for each $i$ and $k$.